# Exporting Highchart to data:image/jpeg

Tags: javascript, highcharts, export-to-pdf

I have looked for info everywhere but i can't find anything about this.

I need to make a report in PDF on some charts that I have in my page. For the pdf making I am going to use jsPDF. But to put images on that pdf i need the images to be in format 'data:image/jpeg;base64' like in this example:

http://jspdf.com/

But I cannot convert highchart to 'data:image/jpeg'. I know highchart can export to jpg or png, but the image is downloaded. I don't want to download it, I need that image in data format. HELP PLEASE

Answer (score 0):

If you can export highchart to `jpg` or `png` then on the link mentioned by you, following is mentioned:

```
// You'll need to make your image into a Data URL
// Use http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker
```

Use the above link to convert `jpg` or `png` into a data url.